# Regular expression in Google Apps script for replace Rs

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm looking to build a regular expression to replace Rs./Re./rs/Rs with Rupee symbol from text like Rs.1,499
I tried following, but it replaces the amount after Rs. as well.

```
treated_value2 = treated_value1.replace(/(rs\.?\s?)\d+/gi,"₹");
```

Comment: `.replace(/rs\.?\s?(\d+)/gi,"₹$1")`. You capture into a group the part you need to keep, and use a backreference to it in the replacement part. Or use a lookahead, `.replace(/rs\.?\s?(?=\d)/gi,"₹")`

Comment: thanks, how do I replace Rs. or Re. with same regex?

Comment: With `/r[es]\.?\s?(\d+)/gi`, see https://regex101.com/r/f7sv1g/1